# Why is the derivative not zero?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, gradient-descent, derivative

I am working with survival models and I am using R's coxph function to learn the Cox proportional hazard model. To try it out, I am using the standard veteran dataset (obtainable by loading the "Survival" library and running data("veteran")). The regression looks like this:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran)


             coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
trt       0.22681   1.25459  0.18811  1.21   0.228
celltype  0.12969   1.13848  0.07765  1.67   0.095
karno    -0.03533   0.96529  0.00540 -6.54 6.1e-11
diagtime  0.00216   1.00217  0.00907  0.24   0.811
age      -0.00364   0.99637  0.00915 -0.40   0.691
prior    -0.00784   0.99219  0.02228 -0.35   0.725

Likelihood ratio test=46  on 6 df, p=2.92e-08
n= 137, number of events= 128
```

I assume, since I did not specify anything special in the call to coxph, that this is learning a Cox proportional hazards model by maximizing the partial likelihood (which is what I want).

The [Wikipedia article on Cox proportional hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) models helpfully has the partial likelihood score function. At the maximum, the score should be zero (or at least near zero). I wanted to try this out to confirm that the maximum was found. I wrote some code in python to check:

```
def gradient(X, y, status, beta):
    # Initialize the value of the gradient.
    val = 0
    # Iterate through the samples.
    for i in xrange(X.shape[0]):
        # For every uncensored example.
        if status[i] == 1:
            # The first part of the derivative.
            val += X[i]
            # The second part of the derivative. I initialize terms
            # beforehand to make computation easier.
            num, denom = 0, 0
            # Iterate through all the other samples.
            for j in xrange(X.shape[0]):
                # If this record had longer observation time that the
                # current uncensored example.
                if y[j] >= y[i]:
                    # Do derivative computations.
                    denom += np.exp(X[j].dot(beta))
                    num += np.exp(X[j].dot(beta)) * X[j]

            # Ad append to the likelihood.
            val -= (num / denom)

    # Return the gradient (normalized by the number of uncensored events).
    return val / X.shape[0]
```

Running the gradient function with parameters close to

```
(0.22, 0.12, -0.35, 0.00216, -0.00364, -0.00784)
```

should give a gradient value close to zero. But it doesn't! It gives:

```
(-43.24273213, -74.49114686, -1774.45727092, -198.37389201, -1537.26179666,-76.08746355).
```

This is really not close to the zero vector. Hence I think I must have implemented the gradient incorrectly, but I can't find my mistake. Can anyone help?

## Edit 1

There was a small bug in the Python program that has now been fixed. The gradient though is still too large. It is now:

```
  (0.0374052    0.29217186  29.11663428   3.23544727 -10.75829199  2.333945  )
```

Which is still very far away from zero.

Comment: The 3rd parameter in your list provided to your Python script is -0.35; the corresponding value in the coxph output is -0.035

Comment: Thank you. You comment allowed me to make some changes and thing work out as they should now :)